# How to prevent zoom-in when clicking in the Leaflet table of contents window?

Tags: leaflet, table-of-contents

The Leaflet [grouped layer control](https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol) plugin has a [demo page](http://ismyrnow.github.io/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol/example/basic.html), where double-clicking within the Table of Contents window has no effect on the map. This sample uses Leaflet 0.73.

When using this plugin with Leaflet 1.x, I'm finding that when I double-click within the table of contents window the map zooms in. You can test this in the simple JSFiddle app [here](https://jsfiddle.net/slead/btsw6peu/).

Are there any workarounds to avoid this behaviour? It's easy to accidentally double-click within the Table of Contents, causing the map to zoom unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a browser-specific bug, it seems. I can replicate it on Chromium browsers as well as Edge, but not on Firefox.

It also seems an issue related to this has been filed already on [their Github](https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol/issues/51).

To quickly fix it yourself, I suggest following the recomendation in that link, and remove the check in the .js yourself:
Change the code at line ca 91

```js
if (L.Browser.touch) {
  L.DomEvent.on(container, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
} else {
  L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(container);
  L.DomEvent.on(container, 'wheel', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
}
```

to

```js
  L.DomEvent.on(container, 'click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
  L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(container);
  L.DomEvent.on(container, 'wheel', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
```

By removing the if/else check on the touch event, propagation of any clicks or mousewheel movements is disabled when inside the layer control container for all devices.

This should be a good-enough interim fix until the plugin is updated to handle touch devices better.